# APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native

Tags: android

I am using **android studio using Kotlin**. when I upload **apk** to play store it shows bellow error..
[image]

I have use defaultConfig in gradle file :

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.apps"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 7
    versionName "1.5"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
    ndk {

       
        abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            universalApk true
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
  
}
```

I have use .so file in my project **armeabi-v7a** folder. here is screen shot

[image]

I have got bellow apks **Generate Singed Apk**

[image]

I tried several time but it shows same error. which apk need to upload .Please help me to solve the problem

Comment: There's a screenshot showing a bunch of armeabi-v7a libraries, but where are the libraries for the other ABIs?

Comment: @Michael sir I am using armeabi-v7a which has 32 bit .so file. I have used only  armeabi-v7a but google play store say the above error...but what i need to do armeabi-v7a libraries